# Execute Alter Tablespace Statement from C# Visual Studio without stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, odbc

I have a requirement to add a datafile or resize datafile from a C# frontend  program without any stored procedure in the database.

How can this be done?

```
Label1.text  =Tablespace name
textbox1.text = location of datafile
textbox2.text = name of the datafile
```

Here is the sample code, but when I run this I get an error:

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqla = @"alter tablespace '" + label1.Text + "' add datafile '" + textBox1.Text + "' size " + textBox2.Text +"M";
    OracleConnection conn3 = new OracleConnection(); 
    conn3.ConnectionString = connectform.connectionString;
    conn3.Open(); 
    OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand("sqla", conn3);
    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn3.Close();
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE. It doesn't execute your code. As such, the `visual-studio` tag is only intended for questions relating to the Visual Studio application, not code you write with it.

Comment: What are the values of `label1.Text`, `textBox1.Text`, and `textBox2.Text`? What is the completed query? You aren't sanitizing the values of these input fields, so I'm assuming some of the text you input breaks your query. Since you haven't provided that, I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: Why are you putting the tablespace name in single quotes (`alter tablespace 'tablespace_name'...`)?

Comment: Your content is really "location of datafile" and "name of datafile"?

Comment: why sqla in quotes: `OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand("sqla", conn3);`

Comment: Yeah this was only because of syntax error

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob Jarvis and Are..here is the correct code

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqla = @"alter tablespace  "+ label1.Text +" add datafile '" + textBox1.Text + "' size " + textBox2.Text +"M";
        OracleConnection conn3 = new OracleConnection(); 
        conn3.ConnectionString = connectform.connectionString;
        conn3.Open(); 
        OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand(sqla, conn3);
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn3.Close();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the driver have a `ExecuteOracleNonQuery` method? Might be worth trying that instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

If no luck with that...

I'm not sure of this, but my suspicion is perhaps the driver does not recognise `ALTER TABLESPACE`.

If that is the case you could try wrapping this in a PLSQL block and using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqla = @"BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter tablespace " + label1.Text + " add datafile '" + textBox1.Text + "' size " + textBox2.Text +"M'; END;";
    OracleConnection conn3 = new OracleConnection(); 
    conn3.ConnectionString = connectform.connectionString;
    conn3.Open(); 
    OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand("sqla", conn3);
    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn3.Close();
}
```

This 'hides' the `ALTER TABLESPACE` from there driver, instead presenting a PLSQL block, which it should happily cope with.